# deleting a row from database using jsp with confirmation wind

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

I really need help, I want to delete a row from my data base, but every time I click on the delete button it only deletes the first element in the table. after clicking on the link which take to "`#myModal`"(a wind will apear), the variable `p.getIdUser()` will contain the id of the first element, not the selected one, while i put this block `<div id="myModal" >` into the "foreach" to avoid loosing the `p.getIdUser()`.

this is my code.

**file.jsp**

```
<c:forEach items="${liste}" var="p" >
                   <tr>
                       <td>${p.getIdUser()}</td>
                       <td>${p.getNom()}</td>
                       <td>${p.getPrenom()}</td>
                       <td>${p.getCin()}</td>
                       <td>${p.getPassword()}</td>   
                       <td>${p.getDateEnt()}</td> 
                       <td>${p.getGrade()}</td> 
                       <td>${p.getEmail()}</td> 
                       <td>${p.getTel()}</td> 
                       <td>${p.getAdr()}</td> 
                       <td>${p.getRole()}</td> 
                       <td>${p.getCodeSite()}</td> 
                       <td> <a href="user.html"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                           <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">${p.getIdUser()}<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>                         
                    </tr>

                    <div class="modal small fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                         <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                          <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h3>
                                           </div>
                                 <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p class="error-text"><i class="fa fa-warning modal-icon"></i>Are you sure you want to delete the user?<br>This cannot be undone.</p>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                                     <a href='DeleteUser?id=${p.getIdUser()}'> <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Modal Popup out Side the forloop,because you are using modal popup in for loop so there create no of modal-popups with same name,or when you click to do your task your last model popup opens---

Do Like that ......... Find solution from [Shouting Code](http://code.shouttoday.com/search/label/Java)
      call Js function(with parameter userId) to set model userId in model-popup
Solution:

```
<c:forEach items="${emailBatchList}" var="emailBatchVar"
   varStatus="statusVar">
   <pg:item>
      <tr>
         <td>${emailBatchVar.date }</td>
         <td>${emailBatchVar.campaignType }</td>
         <td>${emailBatchVar.campaignName }</td>
         <td>${emailBatchVar.noOfEmailsSent }</td>
         <td>${emailBatchVar.deliveryStatus }</td>
         <td>${emailBatchVar.successfullyDelivered }</td>
         <td>${emailBatchVar.sentBy }</td>
         <td>${emailBatchVar.timeOfDispatch }</td>
         <td>
            <div class="deliveryDetail${statusVar.count}"
               hidden="hidden">${emailBatchVar.deliveryDetails}</div>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewDetails"
               onclick="campaignReport(${statusVar.count});"> <i
               class="fa fa-area-chart fa-lg btn-view"></i>
            </a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </pg:item>
</c:forEach>


<!-- Modal PopUp Div For Delivery Details-->
<div id="viewDetails" class="modal fade adjust-modal"
   role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
               aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delivery
               Details
            </h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- Content start -->
            <div class="tab-content emailReport">
               <!--  content will be added dynamicaly -->
            </div>
            <!-- Content end -->
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
               data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Popup Div (view-details) end -->
```

JS

```
function campaignReport(index) {
    $('.tab-content').empty();
    var deliveryDetail = $.parseJSON($('.deliveryDetail'+index).text());
    var tabContent = '';
    if(deliveryDetail != null && deliveryDetail != '')
    {  
        tabContent = '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="table-responsive"><table class="table">'
            +'<tr><td>Requested Mails:</td><td>'+deliveryDetail['requests']
        +'</td></tr><tr><td>Deliverd Mails:</td><td>'+deliveryDetail['delivered']+'</td></tr><tr><td>'
        +'Blocked Mails:</td><td>'+deliveryDetail['blocks']+'</td></tr><tr><td>'
        +'Bounced Mails:</td><td>'+(deliveryDetail['bounces']+deliveryDetail['bounce_drops'])
        +'</td></tr><tr><td>'
        +'Spam Mails:</td><td>'+(deliveryDetail['spam_reports']+deliveryDetail['spam_report_drops'])
        +'</td></tr><tr><td>'
        +'Invalid Mails:</td><td>'+deliveryDetail['invalid_emails']+'</td></tr>'
        +'</table></div></div></div>';
        $('.tab-content.emailReport').append(tabContent);
    }
}
```